# Check user if already exist in joomla

Tags: php, joomla3.0

I have only email Id and i want to check if user already registered with site.
I know by mysql query i can check it. but i want to check it with specific joomla funcion if possible?

```
 $mail_d = abc@gmail.com
    $db     =   JFactory::getDBO() ;
    $db->getQuery( true ) ;
    $query  =   "SELECT id FROM  #__users WHERE email = '".$mail_d."' " ;
    $db->setQuery($query) ;
    $check  =   $db->loadResult() ;
    if($check)
    {
        echo "User Exist";
    }
```

I have checked it with above code. But please help if joomla provide any inbuilt function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get details of a user through user id and username

//Retrieve data through ID

```
$userId = JFactory::getUser($id);
```

//Retrieve data through username

```
jimport('joomla.user.helper');
userId = JUserHelper::getUserId($username);
```

but not through email using Joomla API

```
userId = JFactory::getUser($email);  // Will not work
```

OR

```
jimport('joomla.user.helper');
userId = JUserHelper::getUserId($email); // Will not work
```

So what you are doing is the only way but can be coded in a more better way though

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query = 'SELECT id FROM #__users WHERE email = ' . $db->Quote($email);
$db->setQuery($query, 0, 1);
$check = $db->loadResult();

if($check){
 echo "user exists";
}
```